# How to resolve this error "Failed to send AppEvents" in facebook - IOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

We are using facebook analytics in our project. Application ID and Bundle Id configured perfectly. It was working till yesterday. Suddenly it is not working, We didn't change anything.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"AppActive");

    //NSLog(@"+++ App active Trigger 1");

    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}


     FBSDKLog: Failed to send AppEvents: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#100) Param extinfo[2] must be an integer, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
            body =     {
                error =         {
                    code = 100;
                    "fbtrace_id" = BS3nqPCTUeR;
                    message = "(#100) Param extinfo[2] must be an integer";
                    type = OAuthException;
                };
            };
            code = 400;
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing my Targets>General>Identity>Build from 0.19 to 19.

I started getting the same error today and tracking down the FBSDKAppEvents rabbit hole it turned out that the "Build" number has to be integer now. Don't know what changed on FB server side but apparently we can not use floating point in the Build number.

See, the image, the problem is in extInfo[2], that is _longVersion in FBSDKAppEventsDeviceInfo (line 212).[image]